# Que emulador de movil puedo usar para para probar mis web en pantalla movil

Tags: html5, web, responsive

Me gustaría probar las webs que hago con visual Studio code, en pantalla de smartphone para comprobar que son responsive e ir comprobando las @media.
¿Hay algún emulador en VS code para ello? Como probais los desarrolladores los tamaños?

Comment: Motivo de [cierre](/help/closed-questions): _La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros, herramientas, librerías u otros recursos externos_.

Comment: Abres un navegador, como firefox o chrome, pulas F12 y y te saldrá el inspector de objetos. En dicho inspector veras una barra de menú estrecha de punta a punta. En dicha barra busca un icono que intenta representar un telefono movil por encima de una tablet (más o menos, es para que te hagas a la idea). En firefox queda a la derecha del todo y en crhome a la izquierda. Y con eso puedes jugar con distintos tamaños.  A ver, no es perfecto, pero ya te da una idea de como se verá en esos dispositivos (una vez pulsada puedes cambiar tamaños de dispositivo)